# Preventing barchart overlapping categoryAxis in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, bar-chart

[image]

This kind of CategoryAxis in bar chart by using jQuery - it it possible or not?

Does anyone know how to display this way on bar chart? Please share ...

Answer (score 0):

```
 categoryAxis: {

            field: "PropertyName",
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            },
            //visible: true,
            labels: {

                visible: true,
                //rotation: "270"

                visual: function(e) {



                    var html =$('<span  class="unselcteddiv">'+capitalise(e.value) + '</span>').appendTo(document.body));

                    // Create an empty group that will hold the rendered label
                    var visual = new kendo.drawing.Group();

                    // Store a reference to the target rectangle, see below
                    var rect = e.rect;
                    if(e.dataItem.ShareDiff<0)
                    {
                        // debugger;

                        rect.origin.x =rect.origin.x>0?Math.abs(rect.origin.x)+Math.abs(rect.size.width)+20:rect.origin.x;
                    }
                    kendo.drawing.drawDOM(html)
                                  .done(function(group) {
                                      // Clean-up HTML fragment
                                      html.remove();

                                      // Center the label using Layout
                                      var layout = new kendo.drawing.Layout(rect, {
                                          justifyContent: "right"
                                      });
                                      layout.append(group);
                                      layout.reflow();
                                      // Render the content
                                      visual.append(layout);
                                  });

                    return visual;

                }

            }
        },
```

I Can Use this Code Works Fine.I hope Use Full To Every one Who is Suffer On This Kind Of Issue......